# Just another Steam libGL and swrast error on lubuntu 16.10

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, steam

Yeah, it's one more of these yet again. There are some subtle differences from the ones I've seen and I've wasted enough time troubleshooting stuff for today and it's almost 2 in the morning and I honestly cba anymore. So if anyone here would be so kind to help, that'd be super.

I'll cut to the chase.

Nvidia drivers were purged an reinstalled through Synaptic and "Additional Drivers" several times. Steam was purged and reinstalled from synaptic and Valve several times. The PC was rebooted during that process several times.

This is the log of `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose steam`:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/home/torben/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.8.so.1))
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when you have some [LD](https://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/) loading problem. Usually `export STEAM_RUNTIME=0` is enough to fix everything.

Otherwise see the workaround recommended [here](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4664#issuecomment-254073163).